# Adjust overleaf Page Margins

Tags: margins, leftmargin

[image]

I want to set my page margins as follow
"The margins on each sheet must not be less than 40mm on the left-hand size, 20mm on the right-hand side, 30mm at the top and 20mm at the bottom to allow for binding"

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Image of your code doesn't help much. You should copy code from your editor and insert it in your question (as do @Arun Das in his answer). It is not fun retype code from your image! Please help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check the geometry package in overleaf to change the margin to custom amount? Please check the code below.

[image: Specify margins using the geometry package]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=40mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you this is realy helpful the problem has happened for the cover page as well and half of the text is disappeared (half of the title is shifted to the right and disappeared). How I can fix it